# Overriding certain style in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I would like to add a disclaimer that initially I was thinking to write this in `code review` but since I won't be able to provide fully working code, I decided that `SO` would be a better place for this question.

That being said I have a form (more complicated but I think this is enough)

```
<form class="regular-form">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Where `.regular-form` resides in it's own file `regular-form.css.scss` and describes common styling for all form on the site. More specifically we have this:

```
.regular-form {
  ..
  input { width: 100%; }
}
```

However on some places `width: 100%` is not fitting well so I need to decrease it, but still maintain a common look & feel on the site, which means that I want the styling applied on the forms that need to be tighter to be the same everywhere.

I solved this problem by introducing new class `.small-size` and my question is regarding the usage of this new class.

Eventually what I would like is to be able to do this:

```
<form class="regular-form small-size">
```

But with my limited knowledge on `SASS/scss` the only way I can achieve this behavior is by adding the `.small-size` class inside the `regular-form.css.scss` file underneath the `.regular-form` styles like so

```
.regular-form {
  ..
  input { width: 100%; }
}

.small-size { 
  input { width: 50%; }
}
```

And while that `.small-size` is placed after `.regular-form` class I will be able to apply them on the same level. But this relaying on keeping the order like this forever feels like a wrong way to do it. If someone comes at a later point and introduce some changes so that the order is no more preserved, out of the blue the form will look different and I think this is a big minus of this approach.

The second approach that I can think of is nest the `.small-size` class inside `.regular form` like so

```
.regular-form {
  ..
  input { width: 100%; }
  .small-size { 
    input { width: 50% }
  }
}
```

Now I'm more confident that the styles won't break that easily, if someone is changing the styling at later point, he most probably will take into consideration that `.small-size` is nested and will inspect it's usage, however if I choose this approach the only way that I found so far in order to enforce the `.small-size` styling is by introducing new `<div>` to the form like so

```
<form class="regular-form">
  <div class="small-size">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    ..
  </div>
</form>
```

But now I'm changing the existing `DOM` structure and also make the process of applying the new styling more difficult.

Eventually what I would like to have is nested class like so:

```
.regular-form {
  ..
  input { width: 100%; }
  .small-size { 
    input { width: 50% }
  }
}
```

And being able to apply it's styling like so

```
<form class="regular-form small-size">
```

I know that this somewhat contradicts with the general `CSS` rules but since I'm writing `scss` here I was thinking that there may be a way to make this work, or at least something better than the two options that I have right now.

Comment: If input width is the only issue, maybe could look for a solution to that? If not, you could add a modifier class to the input instead of the form, then `input.is-small {}`...

Comment: @sol The input is one of the changes that should be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the `&` selector in SASS and nest them like this:

```
.regular-form {
    input { 
        width: 100%; 
    }

    &.small-size {
        input { 
            width: 50%; 
        }
    } 
}
```

That way the `.small-size` CSS is only applied when it's on the same hierarchy level as the `.regular-form` selector. This also enable you to keep the HTML as is:

```
<form class="regular-form small-size">
```

Comment: Yup. I was looking exactly for something like this. Thanks.